# I try to upload video own web ste to youtube but always occure error

Tags: php, youtube

An client error occurred: Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 401: youtube.header, Unauthorized)

Comment: Using what code? "Unauthorized" means your credentials are wrong/missing.

Comment: this is give null value .
$media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath)) 
why ?